# How to pass csHtml to ViewComponent in .Net Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I would like to pass csHtml to a ViewComponent like this:

```
<vc:some-component title="Title" 
body="@Html.Raw("<div>this is a nice div, my name is @Model.Name</div>")">
</vc:some-component>
```

As you can see, I want to pass HTML that contains references to variables or the model (that's why I'm calling it csHtml and not just Html).

And here is the ViewComponent code:

```
<div>
    <p>@Model.Title</p>
    @Model.Content
</div>
```

Is this even possible? I've been searching and haven't found any examples of how to do this.

---

Edit: Got it working! Thanks everyone for your help.

Here is some sample code for how to do this:

Calling ViewComponent:

```
@{
    Func<dynamic, object> children =
    @<div>
        <p style="color: white">aaaa</p>
        <p style="color: white">bbbb</p>
        <p style="color: white">bbbb</p>
    </div>;
}

<vc:some-component body=@children>
</vc:some-component>
```

View Component content:

```
@model SomeComponentModel

<div>
    @Model.Body("")
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add the parameters to the ViewComponent and pass them along towards the ViewComponent view itself as you go.

```
<vc:some-component title="Title" 
body="@Html.Raw("<div>this is a nice div, my name is @Model.Name</div>")">
</vc:some-component>
```

or something similar to this

```
 @await Component.InvokeAsync("SomeComponent", new { title="Title", body= Html.Raw($"<div>this is a nice div, my name is {Model.Name}</div>") })
```

Your viewcomponent IViewComponentResult would look something like this, using ViewBag just as example

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string title, string body)
{
    //...
    ViewBag.Content = body;
    ViewBag.Title = title;
    //...
    return View();
}
```

And then in the related ViewComponent View

```
<div>
    <p>@ViewBag.Title</p>
    @ViewBag.Content
</div>
```

Creating a more specific ViewModel to pass along would also be an option ofcourse

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, you have to make a workaround but it is achievable,[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55191327/create-a-viewcomponent-template-container-that-accepts-html-or-other-components) has an example of what you are looking for.

Comment: So it's actually a duplicate question?

Comment: Not exactly but very similar.

Comment: I tried that solution but it's not working for me. When I try to pass the csHtml I get this compile time error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func<dynamic, object>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString'".

Comment: Here's the code:
@{Func<dynamic, object> children =
    @<div>
        <p>aaaa</p>
        <p>bbbb</p>
        <p>ccccc</p>
    </div>}

<vc:some-component body=@children>
</vc:some-component>

Comment: My bad, I missed adding the semicolon. Now it's rendering but on the page it looks like like this "System.Func`2[System.Object,System.Object]", it doesn't render the actual HTML properly.

Comment: Had to call invoke! Now it's all good, will update my question with the solution